# Getting authenticated user in mercurial hook

Tags: python, apache, mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I have an Apache httpd+mod_wsgi+Mercurial setup and I would like to get authenticated user in a hook, specifically `pretxnchangegroup` hook. I have read (most likely incorrectly) that `os.environ['REMOTE_USER']` should contain that info, but doesn't look like it does.

I currently have an extension, that prints `os.environ` to `stderr`.

```python
import sys
import os

def pretxnchangegroup_hook(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'pretxnchangegroup activated'
    print >> sys.stderr, os.environ

def reposetup(ui, repo):
    ui.setconfig('hooks', 'incoming.accesscontrol', pretxnchangegroup_hook)
```

With `hg -v push` this code outputs:

```
remote: calling hook incoming.accesscontrol: <function pretxnchangegroup_hook at 0x7f8310221230>
remote: pretxnchangegroup activated
remote: {'LANG': 'C', 'TERM': 'xterm', 'SHLVL': '2', 'PWD': '/', 'PATH': '/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin', '_': '/usr/sbin/httpd'}
```

Comment: I think that `os.environ['REMOTE_USER']` should do it.  This may be a silly question but is your authentication working - i.e. do you need to type in a username and password to access the Mercurial server?

Comment: Under a WSGI application, it is not in os.environ. It is in the environ dictionary passed to the WSGI application as an argument upon each request. How you access it in your Mercurial code I have node idea.

Comment: @SteveKaye: yes, the authentication is working.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: well, at least I know now that os.environ is not a good place to look for that information

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'm hoping this will help anyone besides me, because I haven't been able to find this mentioned anywhere else.

Authenticated user (`REMOTE_USER`) and a lot of other information can be reached at `repo.ui.environ` map, where `repo` is a parameter passed to a hook.

I imagine this map is the same as the one in `os.environ` under mod_cgi.

Comment: Hey! Could you please give a bit more details on how to achieve this? I am having the very same problem but i am unable to figure out how the `repo` parameter has to be passed to the hook. I tryed printing `sys.argv` in my hook but it only has one entry, which ofc is the script name and path. Thank you very much!

Comment: You shouldn't pass anything to the hook, that's Mercurial's responsibility. You just register it in `reposetup`, and the second parameter of your hook method will be your repo object.

Comment: I got it, thanks. I did not understand (or know about) the difference of mercurials `external` and `in-process` hooks. There is a good example for the syntax to use in the `hg.rc` and the hooks here: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html